TensorBoard in Jupyterlab - only works with strange sequence of commands
I run jupyterlab in a docker container using docker-compose.
Now I observe a strange behaviour that I do not understand.
I use the example from the PyTorch website.
I do the followig scenarios in my jupyter notebook after running the PyTorch example code.
Scenario 1:
Cell 1: %tensorboard --logdir=runs
127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Scenario 2:
Cell 1: %tensorboard --logdir=runs --host=0.0.0.0 --port=6006
127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Cell 2: %tensorboard --logdir=runs
It works! Now tensorboard shows up in the jupyter output.

What am I missing here? Why doesn't scenario 1 work straight away?
The docker container has exposed port 6006 which is assigned to the host port 6007.
I am using:

python 3.12.3.
jupyterlab 4.1.6
tensorflow-cpu 2.16.1
torch 2.2.2
lightning 2.2.2

Update
I figured out that I can run directly the magic command in jupyter if I start tensorboard in the terminal beforehand.

Terminal:

tensorboard --bind_all --logdir=runs


Jupyter:

%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir=runs

Does this make sense?
Is it not possible to start tensorboard directly from jupyter?
